# Overflow menu not showed at action bar

Tags: android, overflow-menu

When I excute te app on the avd emulator the menu i'ts on the action bar but when it's executed on a real device i have to tap the options button to se the menu.I t's something wrong in this code?

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.android.was4fi.MainActivity" >

<item
   android:id="@+id/op1"
   android:showAsAction="never"
   android:title="@string/comite"/>
<item
  android:id="@+id/op2"
  android:showAsAction="never"
  android:title="@string/programa" />
<item
  android:id="@+id/op3"
  android:showAsAction="never"
  android:title="@string/fechas" />
<item
 android:id="@+id/op4"
 android:showAsAction="never"
 android:title="@string/localizacion" />
 </menu>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to force action bar overflow icon to show](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444596/how-to-force-action-bar-overflow-icon-to-show)

Answer (score 0):

As I already mentioned some days back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354064/menu-overflow-3dot-not-visible-on-some-devices/27354118#27354118), the overflow icon is not visible on devices which have the hardware menu button. To enable the action overflow icon, there is a dirty hack that you can do in your application.

```
private void getOverflowMenu() {

     try {
        ViewConfiguration config = ViewConfiguration.get(this);
        Field menuKeyField = ViewConfiguration.class.getDeclaredField("sHasPermanentMenuKey");
        if(menuKeyField != null) {
            menuKeyField.setAccessible(true);
            menuKeyField.setBoolean(config, false);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Call the above method in your `application` class `onCreate()`.